# kext not loaded sometimes

Tags: macos, dpi, kernel-extension

I have some random kext loading issue with a kext developed. Basically kext is written to update the mouse DPI on need. Here are some points related to kext
1. kext driver class is derived from IOHIDEventDriver class, so that pointer movements are modified at dispatchRelativePointerEvent function. Based on the DPI set we will update x and y value at dispatchRelativePointerEvent and we call super::dispatchRelativePointerEvent.
2. Info plist has IOHIDInterface as IOProviderClass, idProduct and idVendor for the device under IOKitPersonalities.
3. kextutil says everything is fine with the built kext.
4. After installing the kext under "/System/Library/Extensions/" we do sudo touch on the same.
5. Finally restart the Machine.

On next start kext loads and finds the device and all works fine. But the problem is if I unload the kext and install the kext again sometimes kext fails to load on next restart. Not sure what is causing the problem. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong ? Is there any issue with the IOKitPersonalities ? If there is any issue with the probe score matching it should happen on every time. Does probe score is causing any issue here?

Comment: When your kext doesn't load, does the device get matched by a system default driver instead? It would be helpful to see your IOKitPersonality dictionary and `ioreg -c <classname> -irl` subtree dumps of the relevant device in both cases, when your driver does get matched, and when it doesn't. Also, have you looked in your system logs? Check both the time when you touch SLE and the time when you expect your module to load & match (system boot, hotplug, whatever).

Comment: Yes. When the kext does not get loaded, device will match the system default. I have checked the kernel log also. I could not find anything which mentions about why the kext loading failed.

Comment: Does it work on hot-plugging then device? (again, ioreg output would be useful)

Comment: Some times it does but sometimes it does not. Loading the kext manually using kextload and plugging the device again will work.

Comment: What about plugging it in when not loading it manually? How reliably does that work? What are the probe scores (shown in ioreg) when Apple's driver matches it and when yours matches it?